# Get public ip address using ADSL ethernet Modem

Tags: linux, networking, router, modem, adsl

i would like to use my D-Link DSL-320B modem as pure modem. Let me explain.

This device is an ADSL Modem with an RJ45 port to which i can connect to, but I think it acts more like a router.. even with NAT disabled. Infact actually i have an internal linux router to which all wifi connects to (i mean, connecting they receive the linux machine as gateway and dns server and it allocates ip address correctly too).

But I tried to connect directly to the modem as router.. and this worked.

I don't want this behaviour.. i would like use my DLINK and receive the pubblic address directly on my linux machine interface.

Is this possible? I think yes, but I don't know how to setup the device this way. From linux side i think that I should use PPPoE-something.

Could you please help me in this? I would like to have, at the end, no ip-address for this device.

Sorry for bad english, and hope I've been clear.

Thanks,

DD

Comment: Why? What do you hope to gain by doing this? Also: are you sure you are going to receive a public IP address? You will receive an IP address, but it will not need to be your public one even if you are paying for it, depends on ISP.

Comment: in my mind i want to "exclude" the dlink from my network. dlink receives a public IP address already, I want this to be forwarded to the Linux interface.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question you want to use the modem purely as an ADSL Modem, and connect a separate router to it, such that the router will be assigned the external IP address.

You need to set the modem into "Bridged Mode". This will cause it to bridge the PPPoE protocol towards your router rather than terminating it internally. Then, you need to configure your router to use PPPoE on that interface.

The procedure for doing this in the modem looks pretty simple. I found a copy of the modem's manual [here](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DSL/DSL%20320B/Manual/DSL_320b_manual_EN_UK.pdf). Page 22 shows how to set it. Be aware that once the modem is in bridged mode it may not be possible to connect to it's management interface at all - some modems I have used do not configure any IP address on any port when in bridged mode, in those modems if you want to change any configuration after setting it to bridged mode you have to do a full factory reset.

The procedure for setting up PPPoE on your router will depend on the router. Most linux based routers will have support for configuring this built in to their GUI administration tools.